# eclipse javascript weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, jsp

I know the title sounds a bit weird but so my problem is.
I am developing a dynamic web project with eclipse/jsp. I am simply trying to bring a pop-up window by calling a javascript function and prevent redirect with a "return false". I will use servlet with ajax so I need to stop the execution with return false.
The problem is javascript methods sometimes work, sometimes the method is not called at all. And sometimes the pop-up comes up yet return false does not effect and page is directed to "test.jsp?filePath="
I am keeping the javascript in a separate file called basic.js.

The JSP :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="javascript/basic.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="showFilePath">
         <input name="filePath" type="text">
         <input type="submit" onclick="shouldWork()">
    </form>
    <p id="output">
</body>
</html>
```

and the javascript method is simply :

```
function shouldWork() {
    alert("hello!");
    return false;
}
```

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using input type=submit, you can use "return false;" onSubmit event of form -

```
<form id="showFilePath" onSubmit="return false;">
             <input name="filePath" type="text">
             <input type="submit" onclick="shouldWork()">
        </form>
```

I would suggest you to use JQuery for ajax. Then use can use preventDefault() method to stop default behavior of form and call your own method -

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
        $(document).on("click", ".#mySubmit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                      url: formURL,
                      cache:'false',
                      type: "POST",
                      success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {   
                        console.log("success");
                     }
                });
        });
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="showFilePath">
         <input name="filePath" type="text">
         <input id="mySubmit" type="submit">
    </form>
    <p id="output">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Saurabh, the onsubmit command works yet the other problems prevail. 
i was going to use jquery for it yet first i had take care of invoking javascript from another file.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<input type="submit" onclick="shouldWork()">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return shouldWork()">
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply,
in your case return false; doesn't work (the url changes). Actually it is quite unstable, different build with no changes yield to different results